# How to display PDF Documents on the browser using a View in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a web application using Laravel 5.8, I'm new to Laravel framework. I would like to display PDF documents on the browser when users click on some buttons. I will allow authenticated users to "View" and "Download" the PDF documents.

I have created a Controller and a Route to allow displaying of the documents. I'm however stuck because I have a lot of documents and I don't know how to use a Laravel VIEW to display and download each document individually.

/* PDFController*/

```
public function view($id)
{
    $file = storage_path('app/pdfs/') . $id . '.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'
        ];

        return response()->download($file, 'Test File', $headers, 'inline');
    } else {
        abort(404, 'File not found!');
    }
}
```

}

/*The Route*/
Route::get('/preview-pdf/{id}', 'PDFController@view');

Comment: You want to embed the file to your blade view?

Comment: Are you wanting to implement this yourself, or would you be open to answers that make use of existing packages?

Comment: @Mateus - I have the PDF files in the directory storage/app/pdfs. I would like users to view and download these documents. I'm confused on how to use blade and property routing for this to work correctly.

Comment: Do you have your file paths stored in database or something like that?

Comment: @Vince - If you know any package that can solve this problem you can share. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Mateus' answer does a good job describing how to setup your controller function to return the PDF file. I would do something like this in your `/routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/show-pdf/{id}', function($id) {
    $file = YourFileModel::find($id);
    return response()->file(storage_path($file->path));
})->name('show-pdf');
```

The other part of your question is how to embed the PDF in your `*.blade.php` view template. For this, I recommend using [PDFObject](https://pdfobject.com/). This is a dead simple PDF viewer JavaScript package that makes embedding PDFs easy.

If you are using `npm`, you can run `npm install pdfobject -S` to install this package. Otherwise, you can serve it from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pdfobject/), or host the script yourself. After including the script, you set it up like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="pdf-viewer"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
<script>
PDFObject.embed("{{ route('show-pdf', ['id' => 1]) }}", "#pdf-viewer");
</script>
```

And that's it — super simple! And, in my opinion, it provides a nicer UX for your users than navigating to a page that shows the PDF all by itself. I hope you find this helpful!

---

**UPDATE:**
After reading your comments on the other answer, I thought you might find [this example](https://pdfobject.com/examples/replace-PDF-with-second-PDF.html) particularly useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Vince and Mateus for your help, let me work this, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad I could help! 

Comment: @Vince - To use this code means I will have to create a Model and my PDFs will be fetched from the Database?

Comment: Not at all -- just an assumption I made.

Comment: @Amos, if this answer solved your problem, please upvote it, and mark it as "accepted" (checkmark) so that it can help others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @Vince- Hi, I haven't found a solution yet. Just managed to create a controller and a route but displaying multiple PDF documents on a blade view is still a challenge.

Comment: This library doesn't work on firefox unfortunately, it forces download.
Is there any solution that works on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

According to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#file-responses):

> The file method may be used to display a file, such as an image or PDF, directly in the user's browser instead of initiating a download.

All you need to do is pass the file path to the method:

```php
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

If you need custom headers:

```php
return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have this code already, but the challenge is how to use the code in my PDFController and create a Blade View that will display different PDF documents on the browser (without users having to leave the dashboard) These different documents will be displayed when the user clicks on a button. For example if the user clicks a button named "Test PDF", they will be able to view the document on the browser.

Comment: You can use `$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);` to list all files inside some directory. Maybe it helps

Comment: @Amos see my answer for a suggestion of how to display your PDFs in your blade view

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/show-pdf/{id}', function($id) {
    $file = YourFileModel::find($id);
    return response()->file(storage_path($file->path));
})->name('show-pdf');
```

Or if file is in public folder

```
Route::get('/show-pdf', function($id='') {
    return response()->file(public_path().'pathtofile.pdf');
})->name('show-pdf');
```

then show in page using

```
<embed src="{{ route('show-pdf') }}" type="text/pdf" >
```