# How to dynamically display multiple PDF documents in a Blade View in Laravel 5.8

Tags: html, laravel

I'm a bit new to Laravel, I'm developing an application using Laravel 5.8. I have many PDF documents that I would like authenticated users to view and download. I have created a Controller that handles both Viewing and Downloading of the documents. Since these are private documents, I've stored them in (storage/app) directory.

I have also create routes to both view and download each PDF document.

Challenge:
How can I dynamically list each PDF document in a Laravel Blade View (I have one view with buttons where users will click and be able to view/download the documents)

```
//Controller
//This code handles downloading of PDF files
    public function download($filename)
    {
        $file=  storage_path('app').'/'.$filename;
        return response()->download($file);
         }

         public function display($filename)
         {
            // This where I should place the logic for displaying each PDF file in a view
            $file=  storage_path('app').'/'.$filename;
            return response()->file($file);
         }

//Routes in web.php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('document/{filename}', 'PDFController@download')->name('document');
    Route::get('showdocument/{filename}', 'PDFController@display')->name('showdocument');
});
```

**I can download a file by going to this URL:**
http://localhost/myapp/public/document/test.pdf
**I can view the PDF on a browser by accessing this URL:**
http://localhost/myapp/public/showdocument/test.pdf

Comment: Since you are [re-asking this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138546/how-to-display-pdf-documents-on-the-browser-using-a-view-in-laravel-5-8), can I assume you have tried the solution I offered and it did not work for you?

Comment: @Vince - Yes, I've tried the solution you offered, even using PDFObject, It didn't work, displaying the documents in a Blade View has really been a challenge.

Comment: Please help, if anyone has a solution for this.